# TypeError: Cannot read property 'choice' of null in Gatsby Link State

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Im Trying to make some ClassName added when i click on submenu from the dropdown navbar
this is what the navbar look like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKZ3A.jpg

the Code is worked before but after restarting gatsby development, it show error TypeError: Cannot read property 'choice' of null

this navbar is a Component, so its always loaded on every page

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <div
            className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto justify-content-around w-100">
                <li className="nav-item"><Link className="nav-link pb-md-3" activeClassName="nav-link-active" to="/">Home</Link></li>
                <li className="nav-item">

                    <div className={window.history.state.choice === 'Convention' ? 'dropdown nav-link pb-md-3 active' : 'dropdown nav-link pb-md-3'}>
                        <div className="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Convention</div>
                        <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"><Link className="dropdown-item" activeClassName="nav-sub-active" to="/convention/general-information" state={{ choice: 'Convention' }}>General Information</Link><Link className="dropdown-item" href="/coming-soon">Plenary & Special Sessions</Link><Link className="dropdown-item" href="/coming-soon">Technology Session</Link>
                            <div
                                className="dropdown-toggle dropdown-item nested-dropitem" id="dropdownMenu1Button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Technical Program</div>
                                <div className="dropright">
                                    <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1"><Link className="dropdown-item" href="/coming-soon">Oral Presentation</Link><Link className="dropdown-item" href="/coming-soon">Poster Presentation</Link></div>
                                </div><Link className="dropdown-item" href="/coming-soon">Download Full Paper</Link><Link className="dropdown-item" href="/coming-soon">Registration</Link></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <div className={window.history.state.choice === 'Exhibition' ? 'dropdown nav-link pb-md-3 active' : 'dropdown nav-link pb-md-3'}>
                        <div className="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Exhibition</div>
                        <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"><Link className="dropdown-item" to="/exhibition/why-exhibit" state={{ choice: 'Exhibition' }}>Why Exhibit?</Link><Link className="dropdown-item" to="/exhibition/book-your-space" state={{ choice: 'Exhibition' }}>Book Your Space</Link><Link className="dropdown-item" href="/coming-soon">Exhibitor Services</Link>
                            <Link
                                className="dropdown-item" to="/exhibition/about-the-venue" state={{ choice: 'Exhibition' }}>About the Venue</Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

As you guys can see, on the Subnav link i put the state name of the parent nav, so when i click the sub nav, there are ternary operator that added active style

im not using ActiveClassName or PartiallyActive because what i want is when i click the sub menu from Convention, the Convention style get changed.

Comment: Looks like `window.history.state` is null. Taking a quick look at the docs, it's an `any`, so null is a reasonable value. Where are trying to set that value? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs:
[gatsby-link](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-link/#pass-state-as-props-to-the-linked-page), you should be able to retrieve state using `location`, but unfortunately, that did not work for me either, and was receiving a similar error like you.

I was able to retrieve state from gatsby `Link` using `window.history.state`
I found the answer here: [gatsby-issue#9091](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/9091)

Answer (score 0):

I see you set the state here:

```
<Link
  className="dropdown-item" 
  to="/exhibition/about-the-venue" 
  state={{ choice: 'Exhibition' }}>
  About the Venue
</Link>
```

But `window.history.state` is only populated when user has already clicked on the link. So on first load, it won't be there. Also, you might run into problem during `gatsby build`, since the `window` object is not available there.

You can either add a null check:

```
const getHistoryState = (prop) => {
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') return
  if (!window.history.state) return
  return window.history.state[prop]
}

<div className={`dropdown nav-link pb-md-3 ${getHistoryState(choice) === 'Exhibition' && 'active'}`}>
```

Or set that property globally:

```
// gatsby-browser.js

export const onClientEntry = () => {
  window.history.pushState({ choice: '...' }, '')
}
```

You'd still need to check for window before using `window.history...` in your component though.

---

To avoid window check completely, use the `location` object passed down by `reach-router` to page components, for example:

```
// src/index.js

export default const IndexPage = ({ location }) => (
  <NavBar location={location} />
)

// NavBar.js

const NavBar = ({ location }) => (
  <div className={`class name here ${location.state && location.state.choice && 'active'}`} />
)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i tried to set the property globally on gatsby-browser then passed down location on my navbar.js component. but now im getting TypeError: location is undefined when i tried to access the props as location.state.choice